# Retry task in queue without causing an error in the monitoring

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

We are using Google App Engine and the built-in TaskQueues to send daily update emails using Mandrill. They are sent at a specific time and there are usually a lot of those. We schedule one task for each email to sent and some of them fail because the Mandrill API times out or we are hitting some rate limit.

Our code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/worker/send_transactional_email/', methods=['POST'])
def worker_send_transactional_mail():

    payload = json.loads(request.values.get('payload'))

    message = {
        'to': [payload.get('to')],
        'subject': payload.get('subject'),
        'from_name': 'Our App',
        'from_email': "noreply@ourapp.local",
        'text': payload.get('body_text')
    }

    mandrill_payload = _get_mandrill_payload(message)

    url = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json"
    req = urllib2.Request(url, mandrill_payload, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.URLError as error:
        logging.info("to: " + unicode(payload.get('to')))
        logging.info("subject: " + unicode(payload.get('subject')))
        logging.info(error.code)
        logging.info(error.read())
        abort(500)
    return 'ok'
```

The solution works pretty well as the tasks which fail will retry later on and usually complete then. The only problem we face is that the failing tasks show up in the error log and cause the Google Cloud Monitoring to report errors.

What I'd like is to replace the `abort(500)` in the `except` block above with something that tells the TaskQueue to retry the task but not to log any error or something. I know I can return any status code other than 200-299 and the TaskQueue will retry but I'm not sure the right way is to return a 301 or something because it's highly misleading.

Comment: Instead of aborting, submit a new task using the task queue API and just return a 200.

Comment: I never though about this. The only problem with this approach is that this can't be done in one atomic step, right? Meaning that between the adding to the task queue and sending back a 200 something might fail and the task would be doubled in the taskqueue!

Answer (score 1):

If you configure retries on the queue, nothing need change in your code, since the 500 response will let the queue logic know to trigger a retry. There should be no need to manually re-enqueue unless you reach max retries in which case you should have some other means of ensuring that you can either definitively track the required completion of the task and re-enqueue or simply catch the last retry by inspecting the `X-Appengine-Taskretrycount` header. As mentioned in the docs, [make sure tasks are idempotent](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#task_retries).

Comment: Yeah, we do not have any problems with the retries. The problem is that the error gets logged and monitoring picks it up. This adds significant noise I'd like to remove.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. You have 3 options as I see it: **1)** separate the task handler into its own module to isolate from any other 500s, **2)** return another code (with various limitations), **3)** make a feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker for the Cloud Platform](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list), with the requested feature being more advanced filtering on graphs of status code responses from a GAE module, allowing one to filter by the route and also logging data in the request.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather have 4) Have a specific function/error code/response message which triggers the retry without all the failing. Like `taskqueue.retry()` which aborts the current request without failing (returning 200) yet issues another retry.

Comment: The quickest way to instantiate such a logic would be to specify "max retries 0" and wrap the entire task execution in a try catch which enqueues a clone of the current task.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Nick's answer of checking the `X-Appengine-Taskretrycount` request header value and setting a handler to terminate, i have this in my Flask app `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
...

@app.before_request
def max_retries_exit():
    max_retries = 5
    task_retries = request.headers.get('X-Appengine-Taskretrycount', '', type=int)
    if task_retries and task_retries > max_retries:
        output = []
        status_code = 200 if request.method in ['GET', 'HEAD'] else 201
        r = make_response(jsonify(output), status_code)
        error_msg = f"Task retries exceeded {task_retries} > {max_retries}"
        r.headers['X-App-Error'] = error_msg
        app.logger.error(error_msg)
        return r
    else:
        return None
```